# UNIX - Rsync with sleep

Tags: linux, bash, unix, jboss, rsync

We are currently moving our servers from windows to linux. I am planning to write a shell script which will stop the jboss service, copy the ear and start the jboss service after copying.

To copy the ear I am planning to use rsync command and seeing some example where people used sleep command with it. I want to know if I need to use sleep or any other command with rsync or if we have any best practices with rsync that I should follow.

Regards,
Pinaki

Comment: why do you need rsync to sleep at all?

Comment: Using `sleep` is worst practices. Someone probably found that jBoss took a while to shut down and didn't find a way to wait for it, so they just added a delay as a workaround.

Comment: Okay,I saw one example in a book where rsync is used with sleep, may be bad example to follow. But what should be the the best way I can accomplish this task.

Comment: Hmm, not clear, " stop the jboss service, copy the ear and start the jboss service after copying" -- doing this on Linux system or Windows? Rsync (or other replication) does not matter; confirming that your 'file is at rest' sounds like the goal - guessing that 'Windows' will need to tell you the status of the file; what commands are used to start/top the process?

Comment: Basically, we are moving our build and Jboss servers from windows to linux. So " stop the jboss service, copy the ear and start the jboss service after copying" - currently doing in windows using powershell commands.  jboss installed as windows services using java service wrapper and using powershell commands we start and stop the server. I am planning to write a shell script for new build server, starting and stopping jboss service is easy in linux. but before starting the jboss services want to confirm files are copied correctly.